# How to avoid O(n+1) problem with peewee object?

Tags: python, peewee

I have these following models in peewee:

db.py

```
class Item(BaseModel):
    item_id = IntegerField()
    item_name = CharField()

class Sales(BaseModel):
    sales_id = IntegerField()

class SalesItem(BaseModel):
    sales_item_id = Integer_Field()
    sales = ForeignKeyField(Sales, backref='items')
    item = ForeignKeyField(Item)
```

view.py

```
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

def html_get(request, sales_id):
    sales = Sales.get(Sales.sales_id==sales_id)
    return templates.templateResponse('view_sales.html',{'sales':sales})
```

view_sales.html

```
Sales: {{ sales.sales_id }}
Items: 
{% for it in sales.items %}
<div>{{ it.item.item_name }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

The problem is the query `sales = Sales.get(Sales.sales_id==sales_id)` generates O(n+1) queries to get to each item's name.  I have tried to create the join `sales = Sales.select(Sales,SalesItem,Item).join(SalesItem).join(Item).where(Sales.sales_id==sales_id)` but it also generates O(n+1) queries.

I looked into using prefetch, but couldn't get it to work.  Any idea how to reduce the queries to O(k) where k=number of tables?

Comment: *“I looked into using prefetch, but couldn't get it to work”* – good idea to show what you tried

Comment: The way you are using the big O notation here is quite strange.

Comment: There is an entire section of the docs you should read: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/relationships.html#avoiding-the-n-1-problem

Comment: Thanks, I didn't quite get the prefetch concept.  I do now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With these updates, the html_get function will perform only one query by joining the Sales and Item models and fetching the related data using Prefetch. This will reduce the number of queries and improve performance.

```
def html_get(request, sales_id):
    sales_query = Sales.select().where(Sales.sales_id == sales_id)
    sales_with_items = prefetch(sales_query, SalesItem.select().join(Item))
    return templates.templateResponse('view_sales.html', {'sales': sales_with_items})
```

Comment: item = ForeignKeyField(Item, backref='sales_items')

Comment: In your second query in prefetch you need to also select from Item, otherwise you're still issuing extra queries for each row.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it in 2 queries, correctly:

```
sales = Sales.select().where(Sales.sales_id == s.sales_id)
q = prefetch(sales, SalesItem.select(SalesItem, Item).join(Item))
for s in q:
    print(s.sales_id)
    for si in s.items:
        print('-', si.item.item_name)
```

Note how in the second query we are selecting from both SalesItem and Item.

This is covered in the docs: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/relationships.html#avoiding-the-n-1-problem